# Laravel Passing parameter frontend required parameter for [Route: user.archive]

Tags: php, laravel

I have previously upgraded the version of my project to Laravel 8 and having a problem getting this error

> Missing required parameter for [Route: user.archive] [URI:
> user/archive/{id}] [Missing parameter: id]

this was the code that was calling the route and passing the parameters

```
 var url = "{{ route('user.archive', ['id' => '']) }}" + "/" + user_id;
```

it was working on my previous version of Laravel

is there other way i can pass the parameter user_id using frontend on routes?

Comment: Make the parameter optional? Don't use `{{ route() }}` but the url?

Comment: Side note, you should be using `@json(route('user.archive', ['id' => 'xxx']))` to ensure proper escaping. Array isn't even needed , just `@json(route('user.archive', 'xxx'))` will suffice since you only have one parameter.

Answer (score 2):

when using this `user/archive/{id}` laravel will understand that the params id is important so it must not be missing or empty when calling `route('user.archive', ['id' => ''])`, there are some solutions to solve this issue:

- make the id params nullable : **(Recommended)**

  add `?` to the id params in the route definition.

  ```
    Route::get('user/archive/{id?}', ...)->name('user.archive');
    //now you can call route('user.archive', ['id' => '']) with no problem.
  ```

Or if you still need to make the id params required and not nullable you can use this trick:

- call the route with a face tmp id and replace it (since you want to use it in js):

  ```
    let base = "{{ route('user.archive', ['id' => 'TMP_VALUE']) }}";
    let actualUrl = base.replace('TMP_VALUE', user_id);
  ```